# How to Refresh a dynamic table without refreshing the whole html page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a dynamic table that displays data from a mysql database. My database is updated every time in the server. I want to refresh only the table every 2 seconds without refreshing the whole page. How can do this? Please help how accomplish this?.
Parts of my table look like this:

```html
<table id="getdata" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#CCFF00">Name</td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCFF00">Comment</td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCFF00">DatePosted</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can do this using ajax

Comment: you'll need some sort of javascript timer to loop the ajax call every # seconds

Comment: I want to refresh the table only and nothing else on the page so how can i do that? can someone give me a full script please.

Comment: Hi guys, please help me with this. I just want to reload/refresh the table only every 5 seconds without refreshing the whole page. Please help me how to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: Also consider the webSocket to avoid fast useless updates

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a client-side scripting language such as javascript in order to be able to refresh certain contents on your HTML page. A very common library that is used is jQuery.

#### PHP

```
# ajax.php
$contents = '<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sound</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Bzzz Bzz</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>';

echo json_encode($content);
```

#### HTML/Javascript

```
<button class="refresher">Refresh table</button>
<table id="table-to-refresh">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.refresher', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            method: get,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                $('#table-to-refresh').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

#### Additional reading

- [jQuery Docs - Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax on an specified time interval like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your_url',
    method: get,
    data:
    {
        var1 : val1
    },
    success: function(response)
    {
        $('#getdata').html(response);       // it will update the html of table body
    }
});
```

Comment: just an example id of table tbody.

Comment: i understand but very confusing and than please add sample html too

Comment: I have added the below javascript to reload the table but no success. Why?
<script type="text/javascript">
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
  ajax: "data.json"
   } );
setInterval( function () {
 table.ajax.reload( null, false ); 
    }, 30000 );
</script>

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load_tweets').load('file.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds



</script>
```

in file put your full html and php sql code like f**ull code by which you are generating that table.**

check this for refrence http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/auto-load-refresh-every-10-seconds-with.html

Comment: Thanks Amit. I have added the below script but still no luck. Where is the data.json coming from? Please explain this for me. Thanks.
<script type="text/javascript">
var table = $('#getdata').DataTable( {
  ajax: "data.json"
   } );
setInterval( function () {
 table.ajax.reload( null, false ); 
    }, 30000 );
</script>

Answer (score 0):

just do this:

```
     $.ajax({
                contentType: contentType,
                dataType: dataType,
                type: type,
                url: urlGetsearch,
                data: '{textvalue: "' + $("#tableId").val() + '" }',

        success: function (textvalue) {

            $("#tableId").html(htmlData);
        },

    });
}
```

The controller is look like this:-

```
         [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult Getsearch(string textvalue)
          {
                      your code.....
          }
```